# Eclipse RCP 3.X to 4 -- classic CSS

Tags: java, css, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a very old 3.X RCP Eclipse project that I am trying to upgrade to 4 but the initial issue I want to fix of the project is to make the style match the RCP classic CSS. I have tried following: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1034649/?srch=3.x+rcp+theme+css#msg_1034649 to create the same style but to no avail so I can only assume I am doing something wrong (surprise surprise). I am very new to RCP so please forgive this explanation. The link talks of an extension point addition which I see in my project.product file but wasn't sure how to add it there so I added it in the plugin.xml.  Overall I'd like to have a better understanding so I can at least get the styling done before I fix some of the other issues.

Adding plugin.xml:

```
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity name="Remove Unused Icons Manager" id="activity.removeUnusedIcons" />
    <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="activity.removeUnusedIcons"
        pattern="org\.eclipse\.ui\.editors/org\.eclipse\.ui\.edit\.text\.gotoLastEditPosition">
    </activityPatternBinding> 
</extension>

<extension
     id="application"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
  <application>
     <run
           class="com.company.project.client.application.Application">
     </run>
  </application>
 </extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
<perspective
        class="com.company.project.client.perspectives.Perspective"
        fixed="false"
        icon="icons/project.png"
        id="project.perspectives.Default"
        name="PROJECT Perspective(Default)">
  </perspective>
  <perspective
        class="com.company.project.client.perspectives.ImportPerspective"
        fixed="false"
        icon="icons/project.png"
        id="project.perspectives.ImportPerspective"
        name="Import Perspective">
  </perspective>
  </extension>
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
        allowMultiple="true"
        category="PROJECT"
        class="com.company.project.client.views.View"
        icon="icons/project.png"
        id="PROJECT.view"
        name="Start Page">
  </view>
  <category
        id="PROJECT"
        name="Sample Category">
  </category>  
 </extension>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <category
        name="Mail"
        id="PROJECT.category">
  </category>
  <command
        name="Open Mailbox"
        description="Opens a mailbox"
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        id="PROJECT.open">
  </command>
  <command
        name="TOGGLE DEFAULT"
        class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState: false"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState">
  </command>
  <command
        name="Open Message Dialog"
        description="Open a message dialog"
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        id="PROJECT.openMessage">
  </command>
  <command
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        description="Opens a new PROJECT Project"
        id="PROJECT.newProject"
        name="New Project">
  </command>
  <command
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        description="Opens a new PROJECT Module"
        id="PROJECT.newModule"
        name="New Module">
  </command>
  <command
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        description="Imports data into PROJECT"
        id="PROJECT.importData"
        name="Import Data">
  </command>
  <command
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        description="Cancels a data import"
        id="PROJECT.cancelImport"
        name="Cancel Import">
  </command>
  <command
        categoryId="PROJECT.category"
        description="Shows the Number Format Dialog"
        id="PROJECT.showNumberFormatDialog"
        name="Number Format Dialog">
  </command>
 </extension>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.exit"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="ALT+F4">
  </key>
 </extension>
 <extension
     id="PROJECT.product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
     <product
        application="PROJECT.application"
        name="PROJECT: DESCRIPTION v1.1.2">
     <property
           name="aboutText"
           value="PROJECT: DESCRIPTION v1.1.2">
     </property>
     <property
       name="csstheme"
       value="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_classic">
     </property>
     <property
       name="applicationcssResources"
       value="images/css/">
    </property>
     <property
           name="windowImages"
           value="icons/CERView.gif">
     </property>
     <property
           name="aboutImage"
           value="images\logo.png">
     </property>
     <property
           name="appName"
           value="PROJECT: DESCRIPTION v1.1.2">
     </property>
  </product>
 </extension>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.Globals"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.ProjectView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.Console"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
   <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.LinkagesView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.Tasks"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.Updates"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.CalculationElements"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.History"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.Excel"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.ImportDataMappingView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.ImportDataWorkbookView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.ImportDataView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.DataView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <view
           id="project.views.DataChangeView"
           ratio="0.5"
           relationship="right"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
 </extension>
 <extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        application="PROJECT.application"
        name="PROJECT: DESCRIPTION">
     <property
           name="windowImages"
           value="icons/CERView.gif,icons/CERView_32.gif,icons/CERView_48.gif">
     </property>
     <property
           name="aboutText"
           value="PROJECT: DESCRIPTION">
     </property>
     <property
           name="aboutImage"
           value="product_lg.gif">
     </property>
     <property
           name="appName"
           value="PROJECT: DESCRIPTION">
     </property>
  </product>
 </extension>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.intro">
  <intro
        class="org.eclipse.ui.intro.config.CustomizableIntroPart"
        icon="icons/project.png"
        id="com.company.PROJECT.intro">
  </intro>
  <introProductBinding
        introId="com.company.PROJECT.intro"
        productId="PROJECT.product">
  </introProductBinding>
 </extension>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.intro.config">
  <config
        content="introContent.xml"
        id="PROJECT.introConfigId"
        introId="com.company.PROJECT.intro">
     <presentation
           home-page-id="root">
        <implementation
              kind="html"
              os="win32,linux,macosx"
              style="content/shared.css">
        </implementation>
     </presentation>
  </config>
 </extension>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.importWizards">
  <category
        id="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.sampleCategory"
        name="Sample File Import">
  </category>
  <wizard
        category="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.sampleCategory"
        class="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.ImportWizard"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        id="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.ImportWizard"
        name="Import Wizard">
     <description>
     </description>
  </wizard>
  <wizard
        category="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.sampleCategory"
        class="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.TagDataWizard"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        id="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.TagDataWizard"
        name="Tag Data">
     <description>
     </description>
  </wizard>
  <wizard
        class="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.EditColumnWizard"
        icon="icons/editColumn.png"
        id="com.company.project.client.gui.wizards.EditColumnWizard"
        name="Edit Column Wizard">
  </wizard>
 </extension>
 <extension
    point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="content/e4_default.css"
        id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_default.noos"
        label="Default theme">
        </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="content/e4_classic_winxp.css"
        id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_classic"
        label="Classic">
    </theme>
  </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: Show us what you have in the plugin.xml

Comment: It's pretty large how would you like to view it? Just as an edit?

Comment: Just edit your question and add the plugin.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was dumb and didn't have -clearPersistedState in the .product (launching tab) which because of this, the css didn't update. The more you know.